# what's the syntax of this c++ snippets?

Tags: c++

After years of java, javascript, python, I am not only forget C++, but also confuse that syntax.

http://heavycoder.com/tutorials/lua_embed.php

```
static const luaL_reg lualibs[] =
{
        { "base",       luaopen_base },
        { NULL,         NULL }
};
```

lualibs init with a 2D array? luaL_reg is a type, but obviously is not a array,

```
const luaL_reg *lib;

for (lib = lualibs; lib->func != NULL; lib++)
{
    lib->func(l);
    lua_settop(l, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`luaL_reg` probably looks something as the below.

```
typedef struct luaL_reg_t {
  char const * const name;
  void(*func)(< type_of_<l> >);
} luaL_reg;
```

---

The members of an object can be set using `{}` as in the below example, which will set the member `name` to point towards the location of `"hello world"` and `func` to have the adress of `my_function`.

```
luaL_reg obj = {"hello world", my_function};
```

---

The syntax shown in the previous snippet can also be used when initializing members of an array. In the below snippet a array of const luaL_reg instances is set to contain two objects, the first one having `name` = `"base"` and `func` set to `luaopen_base`.

To make things clear; the below is **not** a 2D array, but an array of `const luaL_reg` initialized using `{}` to set the members of each instance.

```
static const luaL_reg lualibs[] =
{
  { "base",       luaopen_base },
  { NULL,         NULL }
};
```

---

The last element is used to simplify iterating our array, setting both members to `NULL` makes it easy to see when we have reached the last element.

The loop in the upcoming snippet takes advantage of this. As long as the member `func` isn't equal to `NULL` we haven't gotten to the end of our array.

```
for (lib = lualibs; lib->func != NULL; lib++) {
  lib->func(l);
  lua_settop(l, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`luaL_reg` is a `struct` with 2 elements, [this](http://workspacewhiz.com/Other/LuaState/html/structluaL__reg.html) is what a quick Google search turned up about it.

The first snippet is creating an array of `luaL_reg` `struct`s:

- The first `struct` is initialized with the two values: `{ "base",       luaopen_base }`
- The second `luaL_reg` `struct` in the array is set to: `{ NULL,         NULL }`

Bottom line, it's **not** a 2D array, but an array of `structs`, where each `struct` contains two elements.

The second example should now be fairly self-explanatory; `lib` is a pointer to a `luaL_reg` `struct`.